# Grainy texture from creamed coconut

Tags: texture, coconut

The other day, I made Tom Kha Gai (Thai coconut, chicken, mushroom, etc. soup) using creamed coconut and water, instead of coconut milk. That is, I dissolved/melted the creamed coconut in the hot water, as per normal when using creamed coconut.

The problem was that the texture of my final soup was horrible. It was almost as though it had sand in it! This could have been due to something else, but using creamed coconut was the only real change I made to my usual recipe, so I believe this to be the culprit.

What did I do wrong? How can I use creamed coconut to make a smooth coconut milk/cream?

Comment: Strike 2: 100g creamed coconut dissolved in 350ml of coconut water; same problem (albeit not *quite* as bad). I guess it's down to the quality of my creamed coconut, in terms of how finely it's milled... I'll revert back to tinned coconut milk/cream, I think.